# Footer not getting diplayed correctly in samsung s2, iphone

Tags: iphone, css, android-layout, mobile

I have a mobile website where i am calling my footer through css such that it should always stays at the bottom of the mobile phone screen on load as well as if i scroll throug the scree. It works in a few devices but giving me issues in samsung galaxy s2 and iphone where it hangs some distance above the screem bottom.

I am attaching a screen shot to give a clear picture.

[image: screenshot for footer]

Do you have any idea about the issue could be?

---

### Edit:

Css Code:

```
footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index:3;
```

}

Html Code:

```
<footer>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Sell")" style="color:White; font-weight:bold; font-size:11px;">Sell </a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>

</footer>
```

This works in all major browsers & Mobile phones, but Issue with Iphone, Ipad.
I have searched for this & found that Iphone (Prior to Iphon5) dosen't support **position:Fixed** property, therefore I tried using **"position:absolute"**, but no success. Using **Position:static** puts the footer at bottom of the page not the screen.

Any ideas to resolve this in Iphone & Samsung Galaxy Y & other mobile phones.

Thanks

Comment: set bounces in tableview

Comment: @NANNAV I take it when you say tableview you mean UITableView. If so this is not a UITableView so it doesn't have a property for bounces. I get the impression this is just a website issue.

Comment: tableview.bounces=NO;//iphone

Comment: Well actually, This issue is occured specially in Iphone & sometimes Samsung Galaxy Y Mobile Phones.